# TypeConverters broken for primitive types?

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

I'm running into an issue with the `DecimalConverter` and `Int32Converter` classes, which seem to be returning inconsistent results, as demonstrated by the following simple console program:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var decConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(decimal));
        Console.WriteLine("Converter: {0}", decConverter.GetType().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("CanConvert from int to decimal: {0}", decConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(int)));
        Console.WriteLine("CanConvert to int from decimal: {0}", decConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(int)));

        Console.WriteLine();

        var intConverter =  TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int));
        Console.WriteLine("Converter: {0}", intConverter.GetType().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("CanConvert from int to decimal: {0}", intConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(decimal)));
        Console.WriteLine("CanConvert to int from decimal: {0}", intConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(decimal)));
    }
}
```

The output from this is as follows:

```
Converter: System.ComponentModel.DecimalConverter
CanConvert from int to decimal: False
CanConvert to int from decimal: True

Converter: System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter
CanConvert from int to decimal: False
CanConvert to int from decimal: False
```

Unless I'm understanding TypeConverters incorrectly, the following should hold true:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TypeA)).CanConvertFrom(typeof(TypeB))
```

should give the same result as

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TypeB)).CanConvertTo(typeof(TypeA))
```

At least in the case of `System.Int32` and `System.Decimal`, they do not.

My question is this: Does anybody know if this is by design? Or are the TypeConverters for native types in C# actually broken?

Comment: I don't understand how come you need to convert `int` to `decimal` when deserializing JSON, since JSON contains strings, not `int`s.

Comment: I have expanded my question to clarify. I realize that I could probably handle this by ensuring that I serialize everything as a string on its way down to the browser, but that's not really the question, more a prelude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.int32converter.aspx) for Int32Converter...

> This converter can only convert a 32-bit signed integer object to and
>   from a string.

I agree with @svick in the comments, though, I'm not understanding why you would need to deserialize a JSON string through Int32 to a Decimal in the first place.

Comment: I don't. ASP.NET MVC's default JSON handling does. When submitting an `application/json` request via AJAX, the default `JavaScriptSerializer` will deserialize all whole numbers as Int32 objects. I'm having trouble when the system tries to map those Int32 values back on to a `decimal` property of my Model.

Comment: @BryanRoss Have you seen [this StackOverflow question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964646/javascriptserializer-and-asp-net-mvc-model-binding-yield-different-results) I suspect that it's fairly similar to your problem, in that you need to pass your decimals as quoted strings. The `JavaScriptSerializer` will guess the type incorrectly and end up trying inappropriate conversions based on its bad guess, but explicitly quoting the values will try a string to type conversion which should be a more workable solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I definitely agree with you, and actually I've already arrived at this solution. I still would like to know why TypeConverter's don't report consistent capabilities.

Comment: @BryanRoss Converting a value to and from a string is the most common conversion and, as far as I know, all default `TypeConverter` implementations only perform that single conversion. [Implementing a custom converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) may also an option for extending conversion functionality. I haven't seen an official reason for the decision to only implement a single conversion beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to deal with type converters in cases like this at all. If you want to deserialize your model class, do something like:

```
serializer.Deserialize<Model>(json)
```

And it will take care of all conversions for you.

If you actually need to do the conversion manually, use [`Convert.ToDecimal(integer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal.aspx) (or [`Convert.ChangeType(integer, typeof(decimal))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx)) and it will work correctly.

Comment: It is not my code that is using TypeConverters. It is ASP.NET MVC's. However, the question is about TypeConverters and why they produce inconsistent results, not JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Then maybe that's not the question you should be asking. I think you're doing something wrong with regards to JSON deserialization, it's not the type converters' fault.

Comment: The sample program I posted has nothing to do with json, yet it exhibits the behavior I described and asked about. And as I've stated before, my code is not actually performing the deserialization. It is ASP.NET MVC's code that is. An unquoted number value in the JSON request cannot be mapped back to a decimal property automatically, due to the actual issue that I asked about. not trying to be rude here, I'm fully aware of how to fix my particular JSON problem. It's not an issue. I'm asking very specifically about the behavior of TypeConverters in regards to native numerical types.