# MVC 4: pass complex object to async controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass a list of orderlines to a async controller action using Javascript:

```
var model = "<some JSON string>";
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
  url: "/MyController/MyAction",
  datatype: "json",
  data: { 'orderLines': model},
  success: function(msg) {
     ...
  }
});
```

When I check the model variable in runtime, the values of the orderline properties are set ok. But when I put a breakpoint in my controller action, the properties of the orderline incoming parameter are 0. It looks like the JSON string wasn't properly deserialized.

The controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult AsyncUpdateOrderline(List<OrderLine> orderLines)
{
  ...
}
```

How can I correctly pass a complex object to a async controller action?

Thanks,
Nils

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the request Content-Type header and also use the `JSON.stringify` method to send data to the controller:

```
var model = [
    { quantity: 1, name: 'some name 1' },
    { quantity: 2, name: 'some name 2' }
];

$.ajax({ 
    url: '/MyController/MyAction',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ orderLines: model }),
    success: function(msg) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Notice how the model should not be a JSON string but a javascript array object where each element is reflecting the structure of your `OrderLine` model.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost working now. The only thing that doesn't work: I have a UnitPrice object in the order line. All fields of this object are deserialized ok, except for the Amount field. It's 0 in the controller action whereas it's set with a decimal value in the JSON string. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting it as string in your javascript object. For example: `{ unitPrice: '12.34' }` instead of `{ unitPrice: 12.34 }`. If you are interested in the details about why this is necessary you may take a look at the following answer where I explained this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8968207/29407

Comment: The JSON string is generated by JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj). Is there any smart way of influencing how JavaScriptSerializer handles decimal values? If not, I have to make a dirtier fix.

Comment: I am afraid there isn't. The dirt fix would be to use a string property instead.

Comment: I would like to point out that the contentType: 'application/json' is important.  I missed this first time through.